# Effect of surgery on $S^1 \times S^3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

Suppose we take some $p \in S^3$ and consider a surgery on $S^1 \times S^3$ removing a tubular neighborhood of $S^1 \times p$ and gluing in a $D^2 \times S^2$. What manifold do we get? I've been trying to visualize this, not to much avail.

Comment: S1 x S3 minus such a tubular neighborhood is S1 x D3 so you have S1 x D3 glued to D2 x S2 in the obvious way.  There is a Morse function on S1 x D3 with one critical point of index 0 and one critical point of index 1. There is a Morse function on D2 x S2 with one critical point of index 2 and one critical point of index 4. If you compute the ascending/descending spheres  for the index 1 and 2 crit points you should see that they intersect one point, and you can cancel them to get a Morse function with only 2 crit pts. So your manifold is S4.